# LoginApi ERROR Restsharp.addfile

Tags: docusignapi

Currently using RestSharp V106.1.0 as well a v2.1.8

While attempting to integrate docusign with our application I received an error off of the loginAPI:

```
  string accountId = loginApi(username, password, integratorKey);
```

Receiving this error

> {"Method not found: 'RestSharp.IRestRequest RestSharp.RestRequest.AddFile(System.String, System.Action`1, System.String, System.String)'."}

I have verified all of the parameters have the correct value and I was able to recreate a working API usage in a brand new project without prior packages installed. This leads me to think it is the version of RestSharp that is giving me this issue.Based on research about others having this issue it was an issue of the library change within updates.

Is there a specific version that is required as the dependancies for Docusign Package in visual studio doesn't mention a Restsharp version requirement?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/101, https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/118, https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/126

Comment: As I attempted to read these issues you posted, none of them fixed or we're directly relevant to the issue I had. Unfortunately all versions are looking correct and I'm receiving the issue in the AuthorizationAPI.login function is the exactly line within the loginapi method that is giving me this issue.